# Picker not responding ios React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this custom picker component that responds fine when used in Android, but in IOS it is "stationary" on the first selection and when pressed, doesn't bring up a dialog, doesn't do anything. It is no different than a text element with some "fun" styles haha. Here is the component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Picker, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export class GeneralPicker extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedValue: "",
        };
     }
  render() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.outerContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.labelText}>{this.props.labelText}</Text>
            <Picker prompt='Select' selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue} onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({selectedValue: itemValue})} itemStyle={styles.items} style={styles.inputStyles}>
                <Picker.Item label={this.props.placeholderLabel} value='' />
                <Picker.Item label='Friend' value='friend' />
                <Picker.Item label='Family' value='family' />
                <Picker.Item label='Co Worker' value='coworker' />
            </Picker>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    outerContainer: {
        width: '90%',
        marginBottom: 20,
    },
    labelText: {
        fontFamily: 'rubik-bold',
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#fff',
        marginBottom: 5,
    },
    inputStyles: {
        height: 40,
        borderRadius: 2,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);',
        width: '100%',
    },
    items: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: '#fff',
        fontFamily: 'rubik-bold',
        borderRadius: 2,
        height: 40,
    },
});
```

And again, for some reason it works on Android, but not on IOS. I didn't used to have bounded heights on the individual items, and that made it display all weird in IOS, so when I put the bounded heights on, the weird display wasn't there anymore, but the picker wasn't responsive. And when I say weird display, I mean the picker displayed, with no items "inside the picker", all of the items were at a light opacity about 50 pixels below the picker and were scrollable, but never selectable.

So I guess my question is...**Why does this picker code work on Android, but not IOS?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Picker one work only for Android. 
Need to make changes for IOS

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  Modal,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Platform,
  View,
  Picker,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

class DropDown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    modalVisible: false,
  };
}
render() {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    return (
    <Picker
      selectedValue={this.props.value}
      onValueChange={this.props.onValueChange}>
      {this.props.items.map((i, index) => (
        <Picker.Item key={index} label={i.label} value={i.value} />
      ))}
    </Picker>
  );
} else {
  const selectedItem = this.props.items.find(
    i => i.value === this.props.value
  );
  const selectedLabel = selectedItem ? selectedItem.label : '';
  return (
    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => this.setState({ modalVisible: true })}>

        <TextInput
          pointerEvents="none"
          style={styles.input}
          editable={false}
          placeholder="Select language"
          onChangeText={searchString => {
            this.setState({ searchString });
          }}
          value={selectedLabel}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={this.state.modalVisible}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          onPress={() => this.setState({ modalVisible: false })}>
          <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
              <Text
                style={{ color: 'blue' }}
                onPress={() => this.setState({ modalVisible: false })}>
                Done
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View>
              <Picker
                selectedValue={this.props.value}
                onValueChange={this.props.onValueChange}>
                {this.props.items.map((i, index) => (
                  <Picker.Item
                    key={index}
                    label={i.label}
                    value={i.value}
                  />
                ))}
              </Picker>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
}
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
},
content: {
  marginLeft: 15,
  marginRight: 15,
  marginBottom: 5,
  alignSelf: 'stretch',
  justifyContent: 'center',
},
inputContainer: {
  borderBottomColor: 'gray',
  borderBottomWidth: 1
},
input: {
  height: 40,
  paddingLeft: 8
},
modalContainer: {
  position: 'absolute',
  bottom: 0,
  width: '100%',
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
},
buttonContainer: {
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  padding: 4,
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
},
});

export default DropDown
```

Comment: But in the docs, it says the picker is cross platform. Is that untrue?

Comment: Yes, There are only some component which does not support cross-platform. 
E.g. : Dropdown